# Jump player after touch ground

Tags: javascript, html

When the component or square touches the bottom of the canvas and I press the up arrow afterwards it collides with the bottom,  every jump the component jumps when I press the up arrow it jumps upwards less and less until the component eventually does not jump at all. But the component at the same time moves left and right perfectly still when this problem occurs.
I am controlling the square with the arrow keys and it is the player for this platform game that i am creating and i have no clue how i can change it.

```js
var myGamePiece;
var platformWidth = 500;
var platformX = 0;
var platformY = 250;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    });

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = false;
    });
  },

  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
};

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.gravity = 0.05;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;

  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };

  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;

    this.hitBottom();
  };

  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;

    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;

      if (myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height && myGamePiece.key == 38) {
        this.y = this.speedY;
      }
    }
  };
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();

  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;

  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -5;
  }
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 5;
  }
  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -5;
  } else {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 5;
  }

  if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 5;
  }

  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

startGame();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to reset the gravity speed?

```js
this.hitBottom = function() {
  // ...
  if (this.y > rockbottom) {
    // ...
    this.gravitySpeed = 0; // reset?
  }
};
```

```js
var myGamePiece;
var platformWidth = 360;
var platformX = 0;
var platformY = 120;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new Component(12, 12, "red", 10, 10);
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = platformWidth;
    this.canvas.height = platformY;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    });

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      myGameArea.key = false;
    });
  },

  fill: function(color) {
    this.context.save();
    this.context.fillStyle = color;
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.restore();
  },

  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
};

function Component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.gravity = 0.05;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;

  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };

  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;

    this.hitBottom();
  };

  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;

    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;

      if (myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height && myGamePiece.key == 38) {
        this.y = this.speedY;
      }
      
      this.gravitySpeed = 0; // reset?
    }
  };
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.fill('#DE7');

  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;

  if (myGameArea.key) {
    switch (myGameArea.key) {
      case 37: // left arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = -5;
        break;
      case 38: // up arrow
        myGamePiece.speedY = -5;
        break;
      case 39: // right arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = +5;
        break;
      case 40: // down arrow
      default:
        myGamePiece.speedY = +5;
    }
  }

  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

startGame();
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

---

Here is another approach using classes, you can clean up the vector math, by using actual vector classes e.g. [Victor.js](http://victorjs.org/).

```js
const main = () => {
  new GravityGame({
    width : 360,
    height : 180,
    refreshRate : 20
  }).start();
}

class AbstractGameClient {
  constructor(options) {
    this.refreshRate = options.refreshRate
    this.view = new GameArea({
      width : options.width,
      height : options.height
    })
  }
  
  update() {
    this.view.update()
  }
  
  start() {
    let self = this
    self.intervalId = setInterval(function() { self.update() }, self.refreshRate)
    return self
  }
  
  stop() {
    if (self.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(self.intervalId)
    }
  }
}

class GravityGame extends AbstractGameClient {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
    
    let myGamePiece = new Component({
      width : 12,
      height : 12,
      color : 'red'
    })
    
    this.view.addComponent(myGamePiece)
  }
}

class GameArea {
  constructor(options) {
    let self = this
  
    self.canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    self.width = options.width
    self.height = options.height
    self.key = null
    self.components = []

    self.addListeners()
    self.render()
  }

  render() {
    let self = this
  
    self.canvas.width = self.width
    self.canvas.height = self.height
    self.context = self.canvas.getContext('2d')

    document.body.insertBefore(self.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0])
  }
  
  addComponent(component) {
    this.centerComponent(component)
    this.components.push(component)
  }
  
  addListeners() {
    let self = this;
  
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      self.key = e.keyCode;
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      self.key = false;
    });
  }

  fill(color) {
    this.context.save();
    this.context.fillStyle = color;
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.context.restore();
  }

  clear() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
  
  update() {
    let self = this
    let speed = { x : 0, y : 0 }

    if (self.key) {
      switch (self.key) {
        case 37: // left arrow
          speed.x = -5;
          break;
        case 38: // up arrow
          speed.y = -5;
          break;
        case 39: // right arrow
          speed.x = +5;
          break;
        case 40: // down arrow
        default:
          speed.y = +5;
      }
    }
    
    self.fill('#DE7')
    
    self.components.forEach(component => {
      component.speed.x = speed.x
      component.speed.y = speed.y
      component.reposition(self.context)
      component.redraw(self.context)
    })
  }
  
  centerComponent(component) {
    let xOffset = Math.floor((this.canvas.width / 2) - component.width / 2)
    let yOffset = Math.floor((this.canvas.height / 2) - component.height / 2)
    
    component.position = { x : xOffset, y : yOffset }
  }
};

class Component {
  constructor(options) {
    let self = this
  
    self.width = options.width
    self.height = options.height
    self.position = options.position
    self.color = options.color
    self.type = options.type

    self.speed = { x : 0, y : 0 }
    self.gravity = { x : 0, y : 0.05 };
    self.acceleration = { x : 0, y : 0 };
  }

  redraw(context) {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  reposition(context) {
    let self = this
    
    // Increase acceleration
    self.acceleration.x += self.gravity.x;
    self.acceleration.y += self.gravity.y;
    
    // pos + speed + acceleration
    self.position.x += self.speed.x + self.acceleration.x;
    self.position.y += self.speed.y + self.acceleration.y;

    self.checkBounds(context);
  }

  checkBounds(context) {
    let self = this
    let rockbottom = context.canvas.height - this.height

    if (self.position.y > rockbottom) {
      self.position.y = rockbottom

      if (context.canvas.height - self.height && self.key == 38) {
        self.position.y = self.speed.y
      }
      
      self.acceleration = { x : 0, y : 0 } // reset
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```